# Apache rewrite rule, rewrite parameters to get vars for script, deny access to script

Tags: php, apache

I am trying to get a rewrite rule to take some parameters and convert them to get vars and then pass them to a script.

So I have the following in my .htaccess, which works:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteBase /cms/

RewriteRule ^services$  list.php?type=services  [L]
```

I then wanted to add another rule which **stops direct access of the script** `list.php`. So I added the following:

```
RewriteRule ^list.php   -    [F,NS]
```

Which for some reason just gives me a '**Forbidden**' error whenever I try to access a url such as:

```
/cms/services
```

I assumed that the flags would stop this being accessible if the request was not an internal subrequest but it just seems to stop me accessing the script at all.

Can anyone tell me where I am going wrong here. I have been trying to get my head around this for days. The .htaccess file is in a directory which is accessed via an Alias in the vhost but I know my htaccess is being read as when I remove the second rule the first one works as expected.

Comment: Does it work if you don't trust the [L] flag and put the [F] rule first?

Comment: No, I tried channging it to:

RewriteEngine on

RewriteBase /cms/

RewriteRule ^list.php - [F,NS]

RewriteRule ^services$ list.php?type=services [L]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're right about the subrequest problem. the `[NS]` flag should prevent this rule to be applied on Internal subrequests. I don't know why' it's not working as expected (because you're in a .htaccess and not in a Directory section? because of mod_alias?).
Anyway you could try it with a replacement method which is to test the **REDIRECT_STATUS** environment variable, which as proven to be more reliable than thus flag.

Let's try it (not tested), I prefer to use the long names version for the flags, I think mod_rewrite is already obfuscated enough. Note also the the rules order is **NOT** important. even with the `[last]` flag the result of a rule is re-applied to the rulset.:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /cms/

# RULE 1
# This rule will apply only from  a direct user access.
# If any other rewrite made an internal redirect we'll skeeze that rule
# so if access is provided after an internal redirect it's ok
# we catch it via the env variable REDIRECT_STATUS which must be empty
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$  
# 403 FORBIDDEN if the user request direclty list.php!
RewriteRule ^list.php - [forbidden,last]

# RULE 2
# any request to service is in fact internally
# redirected to list.php?type=services
RewriteRule ^services$  list.php?type=services  [nocase, last]
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I will try this later when I get home.
I had started to look at using RewriteCond to do the same thing but tbh I was determined to work out why the NS flag seemed to be doing nothing.

Comment: I have tested this in work (I shouldn't, but this has really been bugging me) and it seems to work fine. I just had to add a catchall to redirect everythig else that isn't a file to index.php.

So thanks very much for your help. I will sleep better tonight :)

Comment: I think the problem here may have something to do with the rules being  in a .htaccess file as when I have put these rules in the vhost (Include file). They seem to work even when I change it back to using the NS flag rather than RewriteCond like you suggested.

So I guess I need to look into why.

Comment: If you have an access to the vhost forget completly about .htaccess files, appart slowing down apache and adding some problems they won't help you. Add an `AllowOverride None` on `<Directory />` in your vhost. http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/htaccess.html

Answer (score 1):

You should try like this to prevent access to specific file:

```
<files list.php>
order allow,deny
deny from all
</files>
```

Now any attempt to access the list.php file will result in a 403 error message. Same way, you can prevent access to your htaccess file.

Comment: I'll have a go at this later. I am in work at the moment. Thanks for your help.